# Previous element in arrayList

Tags: java, list, swing, arraylist, jframe

using a button I am trying to show the previous element of my arraylist but it does not show the expected result, it only returns the first element,  the data I want to show them in their respective fields in the form

```
public class AutoForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<Car> carsList;

    int counter;

    public AutoForm() {
        initComponents();

        carsList= new ArrayList<Car>();
        counter = 0;

    }

private void BtnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String id = txtId.getText();
        String brand = JcomboBrand.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int doors = Integer.parseInt(SpinnerDoors.getValue().toString());

        Car objCar = new Car();

        objCar.setId(id);
        objCar.setBrand(brand);
        objCar.setDoors(doors);

        carsList.add(objCar);
        counter++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The car was added" + counter);



    }    
private void BtnPreviousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        for (int i = 0; i <= carsList.size(); i++) {
            Car carTemp = carsList.get(i);
            if (counter > 0) {

                counter--;

                txtId.setText(carTemp.getId());
                JcomboBrand.setSelectedItem(carTemp.getBrand());
                SpinnerDoors.setValue(carTemp.getDoors());


            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There are no records");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method names should not start with an upper case character. Variable names should not start with an upper case character. Learn Java standards by following examples and don't make up your own

Comment: When will counter ever be greater than 0? You initialize it to 0, and have code to decrement it, but never increment. I would suggest if you want to show a previous value from the ArrayList there is no need for a loop. You just decrement the "counter" and get the value from the ArrayList based on the new value. But without knowing the context of how the application works you need to solve the details on your own.

Comment: What is the point of adding new code, but ignoring the suggestion to fix the problem? Frankly the code still doesn't make sense. What happens if your add two cars to the ArrayList but then click the "previous" button twice and then add another car. According to your logic there is only a single car because you increment the counter 3 times and decrement it twice, but you have 3 cars on the ArrayList because I don't see where you ever remove a car from the ArrayList. So you definition of "previous" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @camickr Thank you very much for your recommendations, I am very new in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
private void BtnPreviousActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {        
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        Car carTemp = carsList.get(counter);

        txtId.setText(carTemp.getId());
        JcomboBrand.setSelectedItem(carTemp.getBrand());
        SpinnerDoors.setValue(carTemp.getDoors());
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There are no records");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without a comment explaining what the code is intended to do is not very helpful. You need to tell the OP what the problem was and why you changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

```java
break;
```

The break statement causes the loop to terminate after the first iteration. Did you mean to put it in the if-else block?

Comment: if I remove the break, only JOptionPane shows me the amount of data from the arraylist, that is: if there are two data in the                                                                arraylist [0] [1] => "There are no records",   "There are no records".

Comment: Apologies, I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to make it so that once you press the button, the previous car in the list gets shown?

Comment: Exactly, apologize if I did not understand